# how to load data from text file to javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array called `items=["apple","mango","cherry"];`

i wonder how i can load the array data from text file instead of declaring it?the text file data is stored like this "apple","mango","cherry",...

furthermore, how to add to the end of this this text file an item for example add "orange" after "cherry"?

```
items=["apple","mango","cherry"];
    if (items.indexOf(myVariable2) == -1) {

     // not found, so output it
       t++;

    document.myform3.outputtext3.value +=myVariable2+"\n";

    }
```

Comment: Where is your text file stored?

Comment: So is text file local or on a server? Your question is missing this important part...

Comment: First If it is possible, store your data as JSON. Then, follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8951858/1725764) to load the file content and parse it to JSON. [jQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery you can do something like this

```
  $.get("textFile.txt", function(data) {
      var items = data.split(',');
  });
```

You may need something like this though

```
var items = data.replace(/"/g, '').split(',');
```

This is a start.

If this is a user input file then you may need to upload it before you work with it.

Comment: you have to use regex with replace() or only first occurence will be replaced

Comment: connor this script is only run by me i just want to do away to make life easier for myself instead of typing new data to end array manually!i was just looking for way to read and write from txt file . may be i load data from textarea instead but don't know how !

Comment: Well, from what you just said, this looks like what you need

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I don't believe it's quite that simple. Browsers restrict access to local drives (and to server drives) for security reasons.

But one way to access the text file using jQuery would be

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/foo.txt', function(data) {
    var myvar = data;
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply. so you think it is not possible to load from txt file ? how about loading from cookie file or textarea? myvar can be used outside jquery.get ?how?

Comment: @user1788736 simply declare the variable before the .get, and inside the get, instead of using 'var myvar', use 'myvar'

Answer (score 0):

```
 var file = event.target.file;
 var reader = new FileReader();
 var txt=reader.readAsText(file);
 var items=txt.split(",");
```

Comment: Where's the bit that loads the data from a **text file**?

Comment: thanks for reply. that is the question how to load data from text file to array?

Comment: Thought you had covered that part, using `<input type="file"/>` ?