# Load 2d array from file in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows in javascript:

```
var linePoints = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [12, 13]];
```

But I would like to load this from a textfile instead of defining it in the code. The file:

input.txt:

```
0 3
4 8
8 5
12 13
```

I noticed [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901622/how-to-load-data-from-text-file-to-javascript-array) post, which talks about something similar, but for a 1D array. I was wondering if there is a special function to do this for 2D. In java, I would read each line, then split it. But to be fair, I am new with javascript.

Comment: are you using node.js ?

Comment: Not that I know of, I am using it in jquery.flot

Comment: Do you control the format of the input file?

Comment: Yes, I could easily change it so each line is [0,3] for instance.

Comment: I guess in that case, if I prepend the datafile with <script>var linePoints = [ ... etc I could just load it that way. Slightly less pretty as I have different data files, but it could work.

Comment: How about [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) as the format for your data file, then you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (or [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) if using JQuery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
$.get("textFile.txt", function(data) {
      var items = data.split("\r\n").map(function(el){ return el.split(" ");});
  });
```

Here a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/htsf9yBuygAhv7vznS2g?p=preview

Comment: Yes, one additional question. How do I make "items" available outside this function in javascript? It seems to be only in the jquery function. Sorry I'm new with jquery. Is there an easy way to "return" this variable?

Comment: I've tried the following to adapt the code to return data as a variable. 

function showGetResult (name, callback) {
  data= $.get(name, callback);
  items = data.split(/\r?\n/).map( pair => pair.split(/\s+/).map(Number) );
  return items;
}


var items = showGetResult("./moonlight_sonata_diameter.data", function(data){ );

Comment: ok what we are dealing with is asynchronous code, you can deal with async code in few ways, the most common being callbacks and promises, there are other ways too but they don't work in all the browsers

Comment: what you're doing is almost correct but there's basically no way to make your various items contain the result in that way. what you can do instead is to write your logic inside the callback, I'll draft up an example in the next hour

Comment: Yes I just tried that. It works if I draw my plot inside your function (
$(function () {    plot =... etc) . One question with that is, I want to be able to access the plot afterwards (e.g. plot.setCrosshair({x: 100}))   But that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way I can still call the plot afterwards? Now it's not just a global javascript variable anymore. Thanks!

Comment: any chance you can put up a small example? What you can do is to just have var plot; $.get (..); // you can access plot here but may or may not be initialised depending on whether the callback executed

Comment: I've put it here. For some reason the plot is not loading, although I've added all the dependencies. Anyway it might be easier to see what I mean like this. http://plnkr.co/edit/KDiwBj36j9blvamn7g6g?p=preview

Comment: I think the dependencies were the wrong way round, jquery needs to be loaded before jquery flot, I forked it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/PzU4yjzczBuWDGP5MaKL?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. It now works indeed. Maybe there is some way to access plot as a global variable? window.plot or so?

Comment: yes that's correct if you don't put `var` in front of a declaration, it's attached to the global `window` object. so you can do `window.plot` or `plot` and you will be able to access it

Comment: just FYI in general it isn't good practice (e.g. what happens when you want 2 plots) but I think in your case it may be OK if you are just trying to visualise some data

Comment: Actually, I might want more plots on the page. So let me give the other way a go. Although I would rename the plots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121942/discussion-between-michele-ricciardi-and-dorien).

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you leave a comment or accept one?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay attention to different newline styles, and you probably want the array to have numbers, not strings.

So I propose this code:

```
$.get("textFile.txt", function(data) {
    var items = data.split(/\r?\n/).map( pair => pair.split(/\s+/).map(Number) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in generalized function for parsing input the way you want. However you could take advantage of the `String.split()` function which will break a string into any number of smaller strings based on the delineator you pass it:

```
var foo = "0 3";
var bar = foo.split(" "); // split based on single space character
console.log(bar); // ["0", "3"]
```

Comment: What about the line breaks?  Could I use this asychronously?