# Refreshing columns of a row onclick of refresh button using ajax in jsp

Tags: javascript, ajax, jpa

HI i have a table in JSP page with refresh buttons at row level,when i click refresh button it should check database and get those two columns and replace the older values i.e refresh.

this is my jsp page below.

```
<script src="js/jquery1.min.js"></script>
<script
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshRecord(id)
{
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#buto").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".b1").load(".b1");
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".b2").load(".b2");
  alert("value");
  });
  });
}
  <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="rtable">
   <tr> 
   <th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th></th>
   </tr>

   <s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
            <tr>   
            <td class="b1"><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td class="b2"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td>
            <td>tbd</td>

            <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report"</a></td>
            <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="buto"    onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
            </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </table>
```

can any body help in this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another HTML with what you want exactly.**

```
<html>
    <head>

    <style>
         button{color:#127DDB;padding:8px 15px;background-color:#C1DFFA;margin-top:20px;}
         #div1{background-color:#F7FBC9;border:1px solid #F8053E}
         #div2{background-color:#FBDCC9;border:1px solid #F8053E}
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>

    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"testMe.txt", //pls specify correct path of text file and enter json string.
            success:waawSuccess,
            error:ohNoFailure
        });
       });

        function waawSuccess(result){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(result));
            $("#div1").html(obj.name);
            $("#div2").html(obj.place);
        }

        function ohNoFailure(result){
            $("#div1").html("It was a fuilure !!!");
        }

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="div1">old name</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="div2">old place</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>House</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>School</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <button>Run ajax and print here without page refresh!</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**testMe.txt**

```
'{ "name": "John", "place" : "Chicago" }'
```

Comment: thankyou very much,but if i am not using text file,instesd directly i want to use the data from action class,i am not using any text file actually.in action class i have two variables with data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use ajax.

Here are two examples : 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm
http://www.ggkf.com/ajax/onclick-update-with-autosuggestion

Comment: thankyou ,but i am using JPA and no php,can you help by using these.

Comment: Java Persistent API , right ? You told JSP. So I guess the view for your application is JSP. What exactly you need is; a javaClass which can fetch from DB and can give you an output in JsonArray(if possible). I havn't worked in JPA. So I dont know whether it is possible or not.

Comment: One more thing. Ajax is not a language. Simply , it is javascript itself. So it can be used in HTML,PHP,JSP,...or whatever it is.

Comment: view is jsp only,with struts2

Answer (score 0):

Learn how ajax works in a simple HTML...
If you learn this, it's easy for you to implement the same in your application

**Save this HTML in a folder [say ajaxFolder].**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"somePath/testMe.txt", //pls specify correct path of text file and enter something in the file.
        success:function(result){$("#div1").html(result);},
        error:function(result){$("#div1").html("It was a fuilure !!!");}
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Click the button. Ajax will take data from the text file and will show you here.</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**save somePath/testMe.txt somewhere and enter some data in it.**

Comment: ok i got it but ,that action class will return two values in two different variables,and i have to display in two different columns in the same row how i can do that,can u please help

Comment: That's why I told about Json in my first comment. In your action file, put your both variables into a jSon. Then send it to the JSP. Get it through ajax. Extract json(it is something like a key-value pair). Put first key's value in first row. Second one in the second row.

Comment: Encode json in java with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm  and decode with ajax as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: And you can try parsing a json with jQuery in the above example(HTML) itself. Create a jSon string and put it in the text file. And try to parse it with ajax.. Happy coding.. :)