# Ajax Json parsed blank result

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to parse some JSON data through AJAX i followed an example from here:

[how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

On the example, they can get it working, but on my exmaple, the

turned blank.

I tried just echoing the php, the JSON displayed with no problem either. Wondering what the problem is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link type ="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href= "css/bootstrap.css">
 <link type ="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href= "css/account.css">
</head>



 <body>
    <p id="result">fefe</p>>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script>
    $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'GET', 
                    url: 'get.php', 
                    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function (data) { 
                                        var names = data
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>

What the JSON result looks like in php:

    [{"id":"1","userid":"26","title":"654","description":"654"}]
```

Comment: did you json encode the result in the php file ?

Comment: Did you try using this part of the answer?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8951837/3492139

Comment: yup, it echos the result in php

Comment: And yes i used that part of the answer, it doesnt display anything for me

Comment: Try using jsonp (json with padding)

Comment: When you put `console.log(data)` in `success`, what do you see in browser console?

Comment: Is that just an example, or are you trying to use jQuery without including jQuery in head ?

Comment: when i put console.log(data) i got this Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Thats the example, i have the jquery above the ajax

Comment: If i put data: { get_param: 'value' }, then there is nothing in the console

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia JSON with padding???????????

Comment: can you debug the javascript at line var names = data, then type 'data' in console when debugging, what's the result of it, is it an object?

Comment: not sure how to debug but i typed data in console and i got ReferenceError: data is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the type of data?
try add this line in your code on success function

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

is it an array of objects, if yes maybe you can try this

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'get.php', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            // do your things here using data[i].description until data[i].userid
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: console returned this [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: can you add some screenshot of it, or update your question with the data that you get from the console

Comment: that is thing i got from the console, i literally copied and pasted it.

Comment: I added a picture of what it looks lile from the console

Comment: click the triangle in the left to show more detail about it

Comment: can you show more, until it looks like this http://imgur.com/VIuDqwa, it should be only one more click for each object

Comment: Edited added a new screenshot

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56755/discussion-between-kyojimaru-and-clarklight).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "getjobs.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
       $('#result').html(data);

        }
      });
```

Comment: try querying php script directly and check if it works    /getjobs.php?value=

Comment: yup, i have the normal JSON data  like this [{"id":"1","userid":"26","title":"654","description":"654"}]

Comment: Keep the php file in the same folder . or try changing the URL to relative url

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $.ajax's datatype is set to jsonp. Also try to alert the return value.

```
      $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'get.php', 
            data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success: function (data) { 
                alert('data is ::' +data);
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: It gives me GET 404 not found

Comment: change the url to getjobs.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'get.php', 
            data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                 console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

in the console(such as chrome browser`s development tools), you can see the actual result.

Comment: Everything just displays Object i added a screenshot in the question above

Comment: You should not pass the json object to ```$('#result').html()```, ```$('#result').html()``` only accept string value or callback function as parameter.