# readign JSON variable returned by an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I makinn an AJAX call that returns a JSON string. The JSON is either `{"status":"success"}`
 or `{"status":"error"}.`

I want to read the status JSON variable. I tried multiple ways but I wasn't able to get that. As of now I am able to log the string into console.

```
 success: function(data){
        console.log("embedded success");
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(jsondata);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use either dot-notation or bracket-notation for [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). Either of the following will work:

```
console.log(jsondata.status);
console.log(jsondata["status"]);
```