# Live AJAX search mobile numbers

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a web app. Main index page has a big input tag for searching. A person enters a mobile number and through AJAX and php, i do a live search into a MySQL database.

I am being able to retrieve the the required row from the database. I have tried to do a print_r() on the resultant array, and it appears. But when i try to use only an element of the array, it doesn't.

Please see if you can find the problem:

The Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
                if($(this).val().length > 2){
        $.get('php/search.php', {input: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        });
                }
    });
});
</script>
```

php/search.php file is:

```
<?php
require_once 'customer.php';

$input = $_REQUEST['input'];
print_r($cus->read($input));
?>
```

And customer.php file is:

```
public function read($input) {
    //What search needs to do
    //Part 1 - Check if input is a mobile number or Text
    if(is_numeric($input) && strlen($input) > 2){
       //Search in mobile number
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mobile LIKE '{$input}%' LIMIT 1";
       $result = $this->query($sql);
       $output = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
       return $output;
    }else{}
}

$cus = new Customer();
```

[image: When it works, this is what i can see:]

If i remove the print_r function in search.php and in the javascript change the

```
alert(data);
```

to

```
alert(data[0]);
```

i get an alert which says "undefined".[image]

Weirdly if i change to

```
alert(data[id]);
```

nothing happens. but if i change to

```
alert(data[name]);
```

i get undefined again.

Comment: You need to output the data from the php. Try changing the print_r to echo and the JS needs to use `$.parseJSON(data)` first

Comment: PHP must always echo something for AJAX, a return will not do.

Comment: you are having problem in parsing json. you can find few questions on this.

Comment: It will be even better if you handle return data as JSON in your javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: @mplungjan Added the echo. Now for the JS, would need to set that equal to a new array and then use that array?

Comment: There is no array in your code. It is a string that can be parsed into a JS object

Comment: @mplungjan I am sorry but i thought json data works like arrays. In any case, how would i use the .parsejson(data). Read through the other page, but having difficulty understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > 2) {
      $.get('php/search.php', {
        input: val
      }, function(data) {
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (res) alert(res["name"]);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Great! Just wanted to see how exactly $.parseJSON() is used. Many Thanks!