# Send datas to JSON with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

i'm coding a script that send datas (nickname & score) to a JSON file in Jquery but i'm having trouble to make it work.

Here is my Jquery :

```
function addInfos() {
    var nicknameSubmit = $(".nickname").val();
    var scoreSubmit = $(".score").val();

   var newScore = {
        Nickname : nicknameSubmit,
        Score : scoreSubmit
    };

   $.ajax({
        url: './js/scores.json',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(newScore),
        contentType: "application/json",
        complete: console.log(nicknameSubmit + " " + scoreSubmit )
    });
};

$(".submit").click(function(){
    addInfos();
});
```

I used Jquery.post for this ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ )

And here is my JSON file :

```
[{
    "Nickname" : "Alex",
    "Score" : "1000"
 },
 {
    "Nickname" : "Tom",
    "Score" : "0"
 }]
```

The script find the JSON file, it show me the correct values in the console but it doesn't add the values to the JSON file...

Can anyone know where i'm wrong ? Do i do the request properly ?

Thanks in advance,

remid

Comment: I believe you actually need a controller method to update/create that json file.

Comment: it will may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: You are not writing to file

Comment: Also assuming .submit is a submit button, instead attach to the form submit and cancel the submit: `$("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var nickName....`

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but i don't really know how to write into the JSON in jquery, do you know where i can find some informations about it ? I try to don't use PHP for this one

Comment: you need to write a server based file in, for example php to handle the post

Comment: You do not have a choice. You must use a server based process unless your whole thing is on your own local computer, then you could use the file API

Comment: Yeah i think i have to use PHP to store the datas, i'm gonna try to learn more about it, thanks

Comment: You're attempting to use an HTTP request to directly write a file to your webserver.... can you imagine how that might be taken advantage of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your server is webdav compatible, you can't save a file on it via HTTP.
You need to create a server side script (perhaps PHP) that reads "POSTed"values and add them in your JSON file.