# Ajax, JSON objects interaction with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to JSON and ajax. Basically i am trying to fetch the list of events from mysql database & send them as JSON encoded file back to .ajax() & display those event list from that function. I tried different ways but i dont think that i am on the right track. As a newbie to Ajax and JSON, Sending and receiving data using ajax is a bit confusing but interesting

The JSON obects and arrays are confusing me that i get stunned without knowing how to access the inner elements

```
$.ajax({ 
...
...
...
})
.done(function(result)
{
})
```

Is `result` an object or array or string ? should i use `JSON.parse()` method here or should i used the `result` directly for the processing and display of data?

Here is the input format for my backend php file,

```
{"data": 
    {
        "dept": "CSE"
    }
}
```

This input is from a drop-down list,

```
$("#dept_drop_down").on("change", function() {
...
...
})
```

And the output format from my php file is,

```
{
  "data": {
    "status": "success",
    "response_code": "202",
    "events": {
      "1": {
        "name": "Help Dexter",
        "desc": "Help Dexter to Solve the Puzzle",
        "coordinate": "1307",
        "dept": "CSE"
      },
      "2": {
        "name": "Code Hunt",
        "desc": "Lets hunt the CODE ..!!",
        "coordinate": "2145",
        "dept": "CSE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please Help me with the JavaScript code for sending that input format JSON and receiving output format JSON and displaying them using AJAX(format of input & output given above).

Waiting for your help. Thanks in advance...

here is my code ...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#dept_drop_down").on("change", function(){ 
        var dat = $(document.getElementById("dept")).serializeJSON();
        var postdata = JSON.stringify(dat); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "elist.php", 
            type: "POST", 
            data: postdata, 
            datatype: 'application/json', 
            error: function(xhr,a,b){alert("This is "+xhr.status)}, 
            beforeSend: function(){alert("Sending.......")}, 
            success:function(result){ 
                var obj=result; 
                d=$.parseJSON(result); 
                if(obj.data.resopnse_code==202)
                { 
                    //object processing .. Here is the place i need help
                }
                else if(obj.data.response_code==200)
                { 
                    //object processing .. Here is the place i need help
                } 
                else if(obj.data.response_code==201)
                { 
                    //object processing .. Here is the place i need help
                } 
                else if(obj.data.response_code==400)
                { 
                    //object processing .. Here is the place i need help
                } 
            }    
        });     
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: You should console.log(response.data) it looks like it sent back a json obj when you console log the response you should be able to access the properties using dot notation

Comment: @Apb
no thats not a duplicate .. i know how to parse but my problem is with the usage & working with objects and the arrays ... i just wanted to know whether it is necessary to parse ...

Answer (score 1):

result is a string. You can make a JSON object out of it with jQuery.parseJSON.

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
```

You can access the inner elements with the variable you created (in my sample *jsonObj*) and the element's name.

Let's say you want the coordinate of the second event in your JSON, you access it with

```
jsonObj.events.data[1].coordinate
```

That's:

- jsonObj: access the main JSON object
- data: access the data element in *jsonObj*
- events: access *events* in *data*
- [1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrZQrj): access *1* element in *events* element
- coordinate: access *coordinate* in the *second event element*

That would return string "1307"

Overall, Ajax isn't that difficult when you get it and you seem to have a good grasp on it already.

Here's a playground for this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrZQrj

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends what you PHP script returns to the call as Content-Type. For example, let's say we got a json.json file which contains your object text above, I can write the PHP script like this:

```
<?php

$content =file_get_contents ('json.json') ;
echo $content ; // I echo a string here
die ;
```

The Ajax call will receive a text string, because the call defaults to text/plain Content-Type

```
$.post ('php.php', {}, function (ret, status) {
    alert (ret) ; // Will alert text
    if ( typeof ret === 'string' )
        ret =JSON.parse (ret) ;
    alert (ret) ; // Will alert [Object] [Object]
    // ret.data.status == 'success'
}) ;
```

Now, if my PHP script does the following:

```
<?php

$content =file_get_contents ('json.json') ;
header ('Content-Type: application/json') ;
echo $content ; // I echo a string here still
die ;
```

It is different. Now I got a JSON object:

```
$.post ('php.php', {}, function (ret, status) {
    alert (ret) ; // Will alert [Object] [Object]
    if ( typeof ret === 'string' ) // << will not execute anymore
        ret =JSON.parse (ret) ;
    alert (ret) ; // Will alert [Object] [Object]
    // ret.data.status == 'success'
}) ;
```

I left the if() and JSON.parse() in the second one, but they aren't used anymore in the last case.

One last thing, in the PHP code I echo'ed a string coming from a file, but in case you got an object built by the script, here is the code

```
$content =(object)[] ;
$content.data =(object)[ "status" => "success" } ;
...
header ('Content-Type: application/json') ;
echo json_encode ($content) ; // I echo a string here
die ;
```