# Get JSON data with AJAX and then modify raphael.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, raphael

This is what I want to achieve:
I want to create an interactive map using raphael.js.
Using Php, I get datas from MySql DB and converted into a JSON file.
So far so good.

Inside my raphael js file, I must now:

1. get those datas
2. use them in order to modify my raphael file.

I am currently stuck at this first step.

Here's my simplified JSON file (let's call it countries.json) :

```
[
 {
   "id": "1",
   "type": "Country",
   "title": "France",
   "published": "1",
   "description": "Republic"
 },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "type": "Country",
   "title": "Belgium",
   "published": "0",
   "description": "Monarchy"
 }
]
```

Here comes the simplified raphael.js

```
var rsr = Raphael('map', '548', '852');
var countries = [];

var france = rsr.path("M ...  z");
france.data({'published': '1', 'type': '', 'title': '', 'description':''});

var belgium = rsr.path("M ...  z");
belgium.data({'published': '0', 'type': '', 'title': '', 'description':''});

countries.push(france,belgium);
```

At the end of the raphael js, I make an Ajax request (using jquery) to get my JSON datas :

```
 $.ajax({
   type : 'GET',
   url : 'system/modules/countries.json',
   data: {get_param: 'value'},
   dataType : 'json',

   success : function(data, statut){
      console.log(statut);


   },

   error : function(data, statut,erreur){
      console.log(statut);

   },

    complete: function (data) {
       var json = $.parseJSON(data);
       $(json).each(function(i,val){
            $.each(val,function(k,v){
               console.log(k+" : "+ v);
            });
        });

    }

});
```

Here come the troubles:
I get a 'success' status trough the success function.
BUT I got an error while completing the script :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

What did I miss? Can't figure out what is different from http://jsfiddle.net/fyxZt/4/ (see [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript))

That was just for part 1 :-)
Assuming someone could help me to fix that, I still then have no idea how to write js loop that will set the raphael vars attributes as it:

```
var rsr = Raphael('map', '548', '852');
var countries = [];

var france = rsr.path("M ...  z");
france.data({'published': '1', 'type': 'Country', 'title': 'France', 'description':'Country'});

var belgium = rsr.path("M ...  z");
belgium.data({'published': '0', 'type': 'Country', 'title': 'Belgium', 'description':'Monarchy'});

communes.push(france,belgium);
```

Thanks an advance for your help and please excuse my unperfect english!
Vinny

Comment: if the error comes from `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` It might be related to your json file... BTW Your "simplified" json is not a valid one, you should put keys between double-quotes.

Comment: Hi Noodl3, you are right... my mistake: I copied the code from the browser using JSON view plugin. My actual JSON file is actually valid using "keys":"". I edit my post

Comment: As I see nothing wrong with your code, I keep thinking the error comes from the json, as this call would throw the exact same error:
`jQuery.parseJSON( '{ o"name": "John" }' );`. 
Please, check your network tab and see if the json sent by the server is valid.

Comment: Well... I used several JSON validators and all seem fine. Besides, I used  PHP json_encode to  generate my JSON, so it should not be invalid, should it? I wonder if it should'nt have something to do with "responseText" but can't figure it out. I guess the "o" is because script returns "object"...

Comment: oh shit, of course! you are using complete() function, there is no `data` argument passed to this callback, jquery api says:
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )

Comment: OK maybe, I should use success function, that would make more sense. But result is still the same ^^

Comment: that's because you set the dataType to json, it is already parsed

Comment: see my answer, i edited

Answer (score 1):

There is no `data` argument passed to the `complete` callback,
according to [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **complete**
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
>
> (...)The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

So you only need to use the success callback :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'system/modules/countries.json',
  data: {
    get_param: 'value'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data, statut) {
    
    var json = data;
    $(json)
    .each(function (i, val) {
      $.each(val, function (k, v) {
        console.log(k + " : " + v);
      });
    });
  },
  error: function (data, statut, erreur) {
    console.log(statut);

  }
});
```

Concerning your second question, you cannot interact directly with variable name (accessing dynamic variable) in js, so you'll need to create an object where values are indexed by one of your json's values. However, **the cleanest way to handle this would probably be to add your paths to the json**...

```
var rsr = Raphael('map', '548', '852');
var countries = [];

//here I used the "id" property from the json
var paths={
  "1":rsr.path("M ...  z"),
  "2":rsr.path("M ... z")
};

countries.push(france,belgium);

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'system/modules/countries.json',
  data: {
    get_param: 'value'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data, statut) {
    datas.forEach(function (country) {
      paths[country.id].data(country);
    });
  },
  error: function (data, statut, erreur) {
    console.log(statut);

  }
});
```

Comment: GREAT STUFF !!! Thanks a lot... Now I must get to part 2: how to set raphel var attributes with thess nicely recovered JSON datas... Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time NOOdl ^^