# How to compare two value and append it if match any value in jquery loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've selected data from DB by using Ajax and data respond as Json format.
The result is work as well But I'm facing the problems when I want to compare two variables and append the match variables values to a div in Jquery.
I've select join with two tables and I used **fkgid** to compared with **grId** and if this values are equal I will store that equal value in a variable and loop to another index of that array by using javascript with Jquery Library after loop finish I will append that value to a div.

This is my responding data as Json format
As below result I found

when grId = 1 have fk_gid =1 index

when grId = 5 have fkgid = 4 index

when grId = 6 have fkgid = 7 index

when grId = 7 have fkgid = 7 index too

I've imagined that when if **grId** = 1 I will find all **fkgid** which contain value 1 
and if **grId** =2 I will find all **fkgid** value 2 I want that loop to find like this till the loop finish and append to a div.
***But*** I will call **grId** only one times although the result have more than one.

```
[{"grId":"1","fkgid":"1"},{"grId":"5","fkgid":"5"},{"grId":"5","fkgid":"5"},    
{"grId":"5","fkgid":"5"},{"grId":"5","fkgid":"5"},{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},
{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},
{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},{"grId":"6","fkgid":"6"},
{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},
{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"},
{"grId":"7","fkgid":"7"}]
```

This is my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: '<?PHP echo base_url('main/select_cat_by_group');?>',
   dataType: "Json",
   success: function (data) {             
          var output = [];
          $.each(data, function (i, val) {
               if(val.grId == val.fkgid){
                     output += 'this is for match value But it don't filter
                     to find another index if fkgid have more than one';
                }
           }); 
           $(output).appendTo(".get");
   }
})
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you mean `val.fkgid` in the condition, or do you have a variable with that name as well ?

Comment: @adsneo,
I'm sorry I confused val.grId and val.fkgid is the object will call from $.each
And I want to find out if val.grId = 6 (I will call val.grId only one times) and I will find val.fkgid value = 6 (actual have 7 times or 7 index of that array) and I will initial to output variable and try to find another

Comment: I still can't find it Please help