# how to make loop of json data from php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

In my php file

```
foreach($qry_1 as $v)
{       
    $subcat=array('title'=>$v['title'],'cat_id'=>$v['cat_id']);
    echo json_encode($subcat);
}
```

in my jquery file

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:"php/process.php",
    data:{cat_id:cat_id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){

        //how to loop through data to show in div
    });        
}
})
```

in my html file

```
<div id="title">

</div>
```

i want to show my json data in div  so how can i loop through the json data received from php at jquery and how can i show it in my html file

Comment: can you show the json structure

Comment: You probably shouldn't be outputting multiple JSON blocks in the same PHP file. Put each `$subcat` in to an array and then output the whole array otherwise you will not be able to parse the JSON since it will be invalid.

Comment: ^ that, echoing JSON in a loop produces invalid JSON, and had you added an error handler to that ajax call, you would have seen that

Comment: {"title":"mobile","cat_id":"9"}{"title":"pendrive","cat_id":"10"} this is my response which i get @Chris

Comment: {"title":"mobile","cat_id":"9"}{"title":"pendrive","cat_id":"10"} this is my response which i get @user2950720

Comment: @priyabratasen Yes, that is invalid and will not parse.

Comment: thanks for pointing but can u help with solution @Chris

Comment: @priyabratasen As I said, add each `$subcat` to an array and then output the whole JSON encoded array.

Comment: You iterate first, and then, you `echo json_encode()` ***once***, and only ***once***, *always* !

Comment: can you show me the code and guide me @adeneo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

try changing php to:

```
foreach($qry_1 as $v)
{   
    // add to subcat array in each iteration    
    $subcat[]=array('title'=>$v['title'],'cat_id'=>$v['cat_id']);

}
//output final array
echo json_encode($subcat);
```

Then in ajax callback:

```
$.each(data, function(_, item){
    $('#title').append('<p> Title: ' + item.title + '</p>'); 
});
```

Comment: thank you @charlietfl working perfect but when i use it in dropdown button  ie. when i change category dropdown button i got the above json array in another dropdown button but when i again change the category the pevious array not change and it shows along with current array kindly guide me how to destroy previous array

Comment: use `empty()` first if you will be changing content

Comment: can u tell me in which i will put empty() it shows error in php @charlietfl

Comment: can u tell me in which i will put empty() it shows error in php @charlietfl