# how to read json file using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Ok so I want to submit a login page without redirection. And after reading stuff about this, I tried AJAX. So I watched some tutorials about login page using ajax.

My reference is this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkGUL7ZRCTA

What I want to do is that the user needs to login first. But I don't want the page to be redirected. Just check if the password matches the password in the json file. But when I try it, nothing is showing in the console log (I'm using firefox).

I want to do something like this: http://susheel61.0fees.net/ajaxtest.php
but instead of showing the user input under it, it would show "Correct Password" or "Incorrect Password" (after checking the match)

Here are my code snippets:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> AJAX Tutorial</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#loginbox{
    width: 240px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginbox">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />

    <button> Submit </button>

</div>
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("button").click(function (){

        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.post("server.php", {password:password}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["password"])){
 $password = $_POST["password"];

 $jsondata = file_get_contents("CONFIG.json");
 $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

 if ($password == $json["password"]) {
    echo "Welcome";
 } else {
    echo "Wrong Password";
}
}
?>
```

and my JSON

```
{"reset":"12312","sync":"232131","config":"2","bypass":"22","password":"qwerty"}
```

EDIT: I tried using windrunn3r's answer. Everything works fine. But then, I want it that if the password is correct, it would show the (hidden) form. Here is my new HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> AJAX Tutorial</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#loginbox{
    width: 240px;
    height: 140px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="loginbox">
<div id="message"></div>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Current Password" />

    <button> Submit </button>
<div id="container"></div>
</div>

<div id="newpass" style="display: none">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="New Password" />

    <button> Submit </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("button").click(function (){

var password = $("#password").val();


    $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#message").html("Checking...");

            console.log(password)
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: { password: password }, //data to post to server
        error: function (data) {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#container").html("No password was sent");
        }, 
        success: function (data) {
            $("#message").hide();
            console.log(data)
            if (console.log(data)=="Welcome"){
                $("#newpass").show();
            } else {
                $("#container").html("Password Incorrect");
            }
        }
    });
});

    /*$("button").click(function (){

        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.post("server.php", {password:password}, function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if (console.log(data) == "Welcome") {
                document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Password Correct!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "Password Incorrect!";
            }
        });

    });*/
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to parse json data with jquery / javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: I dont know if its a duplicate but I was able to show something on the console when I added <html lang="en"> and <meta charset = "utf-8"> on my HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are using the wrong Jquery function for this. `Jquery.post()` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) only has options for adding a function for a successful execution of the request and the `data` here refers to the data returned by the server. If you want to do something before you send it to the server you may want to use `$.ajax()` to get more options.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (){

    var password = $("#password").val();


        $.ajax({
            url: 'server.php',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                //do what you want to do before sending the data to the server

                console.log(password)
            },
            type: "POST",
            data: { password: password }, //data to post to server
            error: function (data) {
                //do something if an error happends
            }, 
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with server's response
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/windrunn3r1990/Lh46005f/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. I just want to ask another question regarding my first question. See edited portion above.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I had: http://imgur.com/CT7T6gp
Although it shows welcome, it still shows "Password Incorrect" and the hidden form is not shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the success function, try using `data=="Welcome"` instead of `console.log(data)=="Welcome"` for the `if` condition