# Getting data between two strings in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I am working on project that includes scraping data from social media service - Instagram. I already managed to retrieve source code using:

```
            $.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
          if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
            var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
            options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
            //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
          }
        });
```

and `$.get('https://www.instagram.com/manchesterunited,`

I have source file and I need to get informations such as title, description, image link. Everything I need is in this line: http://pastebin.com/Zh0mPGtu

I googled about how to retrieve data between two strings and I can't manage to do it. For example profile full name is between `"full_name": "` and `",`. I tried to do this many many ways but I always failed, here is one of methods I tried: `var title = data.match('"full_name": "(.*)",');`.

Comment: Data on this page is in JSON format. It will be a lot easier for you to parse JSON than to handle it with regex. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Comment: Thanks for help, I am struggling with getting Regex of this: I need to get whole 247 line: http://pastebin.com/bgHNqxXS

Comment: <script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData = {([\s\S]+?)};<\/script>

Answer (score 0):

`'"full_name": "(.*)",'` will take EVERYTHING until the very last `",`

What you need is the non-greedy version (*?): `'"full_name": "(.*?)",'` That should solve your issue. The question mark, marks * or + as non-greedy.