# How do you define a variable in php that can be used with .done in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I have some php logic that results in either :

```
$staus = "pass";
```

or:

```
$status = "fail";
```

Then in my jQuery/Ajax I have:

```
$(function() {
$( "#send" ).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$( "#send" ).prop( "disabled", true );
$( ".loader" ).show();
$( "#send" ).html( "Sending <img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'>" );
var form_data = $( "#contact-form" ).serialize();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'send.php',
  data: form_data
}).done(function(response) {
 if(response.status == "pass")
// console log something here
```

But I am getting "undefined" in the Google Chrome Console when I try to console.log the data.

```
if($_POST) {


$message = "";

if(empty($_POST['first_name'])) {

    $message .= "First name required<br/>";
}

if(empty($_POST['last_name'])) {

    $message .= "Last name required";
}

if($message) {

    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $message . "</div>";
    $pass = "error";

} else {

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>Form submitted successfully</div>";
    $pass = "succeed";
}
}
```

Comment: Could you include more of the jQuery code?

Comment: yes, this stuff is not sufficient to give your answer

Comment: Going to edit now...

Comment: Please add more information like what format response is in and what is the contentType in Ajax request.

Comment: show your php code to give perfect reply.

Comment: @Jonathan is the php you have shown, `send.php`?

Comment: yes, send.php contains the php code I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$( "#send" ).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$( "#send" ).prop( "disabled", true );
$( ".loader" ).show();
$( "#send" ).html( "Sending <img src='img/ajax-loader.gif'>" );
var form_data = $( "#contact-form" ).serialize();
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'send.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(json){
 if(json['error'])
{
$('#your_notification_div').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" +json['message']+ "</div>")
}
else
{
$('#your_notification_div').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+json['message']+"</div>")

}
}
});
});
});
```

Edit the validation PHP file:

```
    if($_POST) {
    $json = array();
    $message = '';
    if(empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
        $json['error'] = 'true';
        $message .=  "First name required<br/>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
        $json['error'] = 'true';
        $message .=  "Last name required";
    }
    if(!isset($json['error'])) {
        $json['success'] = 'true';
        $message = 'Form submitted successfully';
    }
    $json['message'] = $message;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean? Would I have to change other code or could I just replace the success with .done?

Comment: please replace my code snippet and let me know if it works.

Comment: Nothing happens when I use this code. There is nothing displayed on the page and there is no console output

Comment: can you check for js errors, as I have not tested it

Comment: In console? Or how?

Comment: on Chrome: Right click and "Inspect Element" and checkout the "Console" tab

Comment: Yeah, I did that. There was a simple error about the ) or } but I fixed it and now there are no console errors.

Comment: Thank you. Still nothing happens and there is no error in console. There was an extra } in the php which I fixed but still nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142136/discussion-between-zaman-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like:

```html
<?php
  $staus = "pass";
  ?>
  <script>
    const staus = <?php echo $staus?>
    console.log(staus);
  </script>
  <?php
  // PHP Code...
?>
```

I do something like that in EJS(Node)

Answer (score 0):

in ajax response you will get all echo value from PHP. if you want your ajax to give you result in variable then you can use JSON data type to retrieve data in array. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript) link for more details