# ajax cant get json data from url

Tags: php, json, ajax, url, localhost

Hi i want make simple call data with some ajax and json

i have json data in this url : http://webqu.hostoi.com/webqu/php/data.php

this is my php code

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kasir";
$hasil = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$results = array();

foreach($hasil as $row){
     $results[] = array(          
          'ID_Kasir'=> $row[ID_Kasir],
          'Kasir_username'=> $row[Kasir_Username],
          'Password'=> $row[Password],
          'Nama'=> $row[Nama],
          'ID_Jenis_kelamin'=> $row[ID_Jenis_kelamin],          
     );
}
$json = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
header('Content-type: application/json');
//header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=kasir.json');
echo $json;
```

and i call it with some ajax function like this

```js
$.ajax({            
  url         : "http://webqu.hostoi.com/webqu/php/data.php",
  dataType    : "json",
  success     : function(data){}
      });
```

but i cant get data from that, i use it with dataType : jsonp too

i can get data if running in localhost

i hope u can help me
Thx :D

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

One issue you'll be experiencing is the fact you can't iterate through the mysqli response resource using `foreach()`, you need to convert the resource to an array first. Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM kasir";
$hasil = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$results = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil)){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it same, still cant get data from url T_T

Comment: This is just one issue I saw, not a complete fix.