# show image from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting response in jquery as below. I want to show images from the db through the ajax request. 
My controller code :

```
public function images($id='')
    {           
        $this->load->model('gallery');
        $data = this->gallery_model->getimages($this->input->post('id')); 
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

My ajax :

```
function imageslide(folderid){

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/images",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id: folderid},
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
        resultObj = eval (result);
        alert(JSON.stringify(resultObj));
      }else{
        alert("error");
      }
    }
});
```

The result which i received in the `Network` tab is

```
[{"id":"153","file_name":"DSC00081.JPG","created":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","modified":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","status":null,"folder_id":"50"},{"id":"154","file_name":"DSC00082.JPG","created":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","modified":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","status":null,"folder_id":"50"},{"id":"155","file_name":"DSC00083.JPG","created":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","modified":"2017-05-23 09:36:32","status":null,"folder_id":"50"}]
```

[image: The output from browser showing alert message]

I do not know how to show image in the browser in the `<img>` tag. As you can see, I am getting `jpeg` in the alert window.  Kindly help me through.. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are just getting the file_name of image instead of the image code, you will either need to store the image code into blob format inside the database field and retrieve and generate back image, or you will need to store image on logical path and generate path to retrieve the image from that path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951858/4229270

Comment: fyi `eval(result);` is pointless, if you're returning a JSON object you shouldn't have to do anything to it as valid JSON is also valid as a JS object. If you're getting a string use `JSON.parse()` instead.

Comment: ok how to `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the imagen using jQuery, for example with the first index of array:

```
$('#container').append('<img src="' + result[0].file_name + '" />');
```

If you want to add each image, you can use forEach loop.

```
result.forEach(function (image) {
    $('#container').append('<img src="' + image.file_name + '" />');
});
```

Comment: No, only need to have an container (for example a div) to append the content

Comment: i kept the code inside the success function of my ajax, it didnot worked for me..and also created a div with id='container'

Comment: Perez Gonda, Sorry i made a mistake in the div. I corrected and it worked with the following error GET http://localhost/ins/index.php/welcome/DSC00081.JPG 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please check if the image exists, or it have the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Copying from your code

function imageslide(folderid){

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/images",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id: folderid},
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
        resultObj = eval (result);
        var HTMLbuilder = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < resultObj.length; i++){
            var imgHtml = "<img src='path-toImage/" + resultObj[i].file_name + "'>";
            HTMLbuilder = HTMLbuilder + imgHtml;
        }
        $("#imgContainer").html(HTMLbuilder);
      }else{
        alert("error");
      }
    }
});
```

Don't forget to have the div with the appropriate ID on the HTML

```
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I worked with the help of your code, I get the following,`DSC00082.JPG:1 GET http://localhost/ins/index.php/welcome/path-toImage/DSC00082.JPG 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @PeniyalAbraham you need to check the actual path to your image. Replace the "path-toImage" in the code to the relative path of the image

Answer (score 0):

On pure js:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lUcRSyLnxRX4V15wvMcX?p=preview)

```
result.forEach(img => {
      let element = document.createElement('img');
      element.width = '100'
      element.src = img.path;
      parentEl.appendChild(element)
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You have received JSON object in `result`. Just loop through it, using

`$.each(result, function(key, value){ 
     $('#container').append('<img src=" +value.file_name + " />');
 })`