# Can't get the value of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json object, and i want to get the value of the error but it always returning me an undefined result.

Here is the json object

> ```
> {"isValid":false,"errors":["Username is required.","Password is required."]}
> ```

my code is:

```
success: function (response) {

                var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(response);                    
                var JSONobject = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

                alert(JSONstring);
                alert(JSONobject);



                console.log(JSONobject);                    
                var _result = JSONobject.errors;
```

i have also tried:

```
var _result = JSONobject[0]['errors'];
var _result = JSONobject['errors'][0];
```

but still i can't access the value.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(response)` you dont do this step. It is already a string, unless it's parsed before hand which you wouldnt need either step in that case

Comment: Do you have `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` options?

Comment: @Barmar yes i have.

Here it is:
 $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    UserName: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    Password: $('#txtPassword').val()
                },
                dataType: "json",

Comment: When you use `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery parses it for you. You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` or `JSON.parse()` yourself. `response` contains the object.

Comment: It returning me an undefined result if i don't call `JSON.stringify()` or `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have access to the JSON object you can work with it without manipulation.  If your question was also looking to get it in that form, see this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951858/9439488) answer for how to format your request.

```
success: function (response) {
    // Assuming response = {"isValid":false,"errors":["Username is required.","Password is required."]}

    // Directly access the property errors
    var errors = response.errors;
    console.log(errors); // ["Username is required.","Password is required."]
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13hgmj8b/)

Comment: it returning me undefined when i try the above code.

Comment: it gives me this
`undefined`
`"{\"isValid\":false,\"errors\":[\"Username is required.\",\"Password is required.\"]}"`
`{"isValid":false,"errors":["Username is required.","Password is required."]}`

`success: function (response) {
                      
                    var _result = response.errors;                   
                    
                    console.log(_result);`
`var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(response);                  
                    var JSONobject = JSON.parse(JSONstring);`

Comment: `console.log(JSONstring);
                    console.log(JSONobject);`

Comment: If you provide us a bigger code sample on something like JSFiddle we could potentially help more.

Comment: Actually the response comes from my controller:
    `var _errors = new
            {
                isValid = ModelState.IsValid,
                errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors)
                .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)

            };

            string errors = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_errors);
            return Json(errors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`