# JS Function including AJAX returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
function idToUnitNum(id){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajax_officerFromId.php",
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function(dataString) {
            ofd = JSON.parse(dataString);
            var result = ofd.data;
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

This is the function. It's called from another function. I tried testing it's output by logging result before it returns, and it displays the appropriate result.

Result (JSON):

```
{"success":"true","time":1524462577,"data":"ADMIN"}
```

However, when I try catching the variable (a string), it does shows as "undefined".

It's probably a stupid mistake.

Calling the function:

```
var unitnum = idToUnitNum(adata.arresting_officer);
console.log(unitnum);
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: what are you getting in the `dataString` response?

Comment: @prakashtank edited to include `dataString` (the AJAX result)

Comment: @JerrySmithHF : please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript
include : `dataType: 'json',` in your ajax call and remove parsing and then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function idToUnitNum(id){
    var result = '';
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajax_officerFromId.php",
        async: false,
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function(dataString) {
            ofd = JSON.parse(dataString);
            result = ofd.data;

        }
    });
return result;
}
```

Thank you to whoever suggested I turn off async and call it outside fo the AJAX request. Solved the issue.

Comment: Don’t disable async. This will block the rest of your code, which provide a terrible user experience. It’s async by default for a good reason

Answer (score 0):

pass callback function to idToUnitNum. something like below

```
function idToUnitNum(id,callback){
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax_officerFromId.php",
    data: {'id': id},
    success: function(dataString) {
        ofd = JSON.parse(dataString);
        var result = ofd.data;
        console.log(result);
        callback(result);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please change the AJAX function like this :

```
function idToUnitNum(id){
var dfd = $.Deferred();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax_officerFromId.php",
    data: {'id': id},
    success: function(dataString) {
        ofd = JSON.parse(dataString);
        var result = ofd.data;
         dfd.resolve(result);
       // return result;
    }
});
 return dfd.promise();
}
```

And you can use this function like this

```
idToUnitNum(adata.arresting_officer).done(function(response){
   console.log(response);
});
```

FYI : not tested code

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a callback function as a parameter or, even better, use promises. Simply put return in front of your ajax call and call .then() on the return value to read the result when it is available.

This has been asked many times, so you shouldn’t have any trouble finding more information about these solutions

Comment: Also check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316805/4136777