# Access property of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I will please need another pair of eyes on this. I am getting historical data from cryptocompare API and can't access the values I receive.

[image: Response]

When I hardcode it, something like `res.data.OMG.USD`, I am able to get the result.

These is the exact format it comes in. I tried parsing it into a string and pushing the results into an array but haven't been able to access the prices, when I did Object.key, it returned only the name and not the USD or EUR values. What am I missing here?

UPDATE:here is the request, I am trying to access the USD values.

```
 $http.get(
        'data/pricehistorical?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR'
          ).then(
            function(res) {
           //sample response
          /*

          {"OMG":{"USD":8.19,"EUR":6.65}}
          {"BTC":{"USD":10226.86,"EUR":8153.29}}
          */
     },

  function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Yes, I get this error. ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: Your object only has one key so `Object.keys()` will only give that to you. That key points to another object with its own keys. It would be helpful if you showed a little more detail about what you're trying to do and what you are starting with (i.e do you have an array of these objects?)

Comment: p.s. your get that `JSON.parse()` error when it's already a javascript object. It doesn't need to be parsed,

Comment: yes I did ```typeof(data)``` to confirm that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON data with jQuery / JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: @Shadow I have seen that question, non of the answers worked for me.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what your question is... Try adding a [mcve] so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Does your `res` have both those values (i.e. an array) or do you just get one of them?

Comment: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR&ts=1452680400   @Mark_M it's one, an example is on this link

Comment: IMHO if you provide exactly value sending to you by server then this value is not a well-formed JSON. Indeed in this case JSON.parse fails with error.

Comment: You can just look at the `Object.values()` in that case: `let quote = Object.values(res)[0];` then your value you will be in `quote.USD` You need the `[0]` because an object potentially has more than one value, but in your case it doesn't.

Comment: Your sample response is not any kind of valid format usable by JavaScript. Using the link you provided above gives `{"BTC":{"USD":9093.86,"EUR":7598.64}}` which is valid. What is `$http`? Does it automatically parse JSON responses into JavaScript objects?

Comment: @Mark_M it worked! I now have access to the values. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Phil I copied the response directly from the console,  `$http` because I am using angularjs

Comment: Which _"console"_ did you copy that from? The only one I'd be looking at is the _Network_ console in the _Response_ tab.

Comment: Yep, I copied it from the network console. I have  updated the question with a screenshot from the Network>Response tab

Comment: So you can see that it looks nothing like what you originally had. All you should need is `res.data.OMG.USD`, `res.data.OMG.EUR`, etc. What exactly is you question now?

Comment: "When I hardcode it, something like `res.data.OMG.USD`, I am able to get the result." and it's the same thing as what I pasted in the response portion of the code snippet .

Comment: I could have framed the in a more concise manner, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to understand what `JSON` format is.

Supposing that you have already studied it then writing pure Javascript code:

```js
var testObject = {"OMG": {"USD": 15.85, "EUR": 12.62}};

//Then you can access USD by

console.log(testObject.OMG.USD);
```

Comment: As you can see in the question, I stated that I was able to access it that way, please follow the comments to see how we arrived at an answer that worked for me.