# phalcon dependent dropdown list population with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, phalcon

in phalcon framework i want to populate dependent drop down category list. But i'm facing some problems in my code:

#1. On select category list -> subcategory list shows: undefined (it's not populating options with value)

#2. if database have no data console.log shows: Undefined variable: resData in my controller
 #3. if select category which value is '0' its not disabling the subcategory list again
What i'm doing wrong in my code?
[image]

[Module.php]

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt;

$di->setShared('view', function () use ($config){
    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir(APP_PATH . $config->appB->viewsDir);
# Register Volt Template           
    $view->registerEngines(array( 
    ".volt" => function($view, $di) use ($config) {
        $volt = new Volt($view, $di);
        $volt->setOptions(
            array(
                'compiledPath'      => APP_PATH . $config->appB->cacheDir,
                'compiledExtension' => '.php',
                'compiledSeparator' => '_',
                'compileAlways'     => true,
                'autoescape'        => false,
                'stat'              => true
            )
        );
    $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
    $compiler->addFunction('strtotime','strtotime');

    return $volt;
    }
    ));            
    return $view;
});
```

[CONTROLLER]

```
public function entryAction()
{
        $formAction = 'backend/index/insert';
        $this->view->setVar('action',$formAction);
        $this->view->product_title = '';
        $this->view->product_price = '';
        $this->view->product_keyword = '';
        $this->view->product_image = '';
        $this->view->product_desc = '';
        $category = Categories::find();
        $this->view->setVar('categories',$category);                       
        $this->view->pick("index/entry");
}

public function getSubcategoryAction()
{ 
    $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
    $data = Subcat::findBycategory_id($id); 
    $resData = array();    
    foreach($data as $result)
    {
        $resData[] = array('id' => $result->id, 'category_id' => $result->category_id, 'subcategory' => $result->subcategory_name);
    }
    echo(json_encode($resData));       
    //$this->view->setVar('subcategory',$resData);
}
```

[ENTRY VOLT]

```
Category:<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="0">Choose Category ...</option>
{% for category in categories %}
    <option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.categoryname}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select><br/>
sub-Category:<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" disabled="disabled"><option value="0">Choose Sub-Category ...</option></select>
<br/>
    Products:<select name="products" id="products" disabled="disabled"><option value="0">Choose a Product ...</option></select>
<br/>
```

[JQUERY]

```
$("select[name='category']").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled", false); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getSubcategory",
        data:'id='+value,       
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#subcategory").not(":first").remove();
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(value){               
            $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.subcategory+'</option>');
        });

    }).fail(function(){
            console.log('error: Please reload page and try again!');
    }).always(function(){
            console.log('Complete:');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow This and just update your code...

[JQuery]

```
$("select[name='category']").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value === '0'){$("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled", true); $("select[name='products']").attr("disabled", true);}else{$("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled", false);} 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getSubcategory",
        data:'id='+value,       
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#subcategory").find('option').not(":first").remove();    
        $("#products").find('option').not(":first").remove();
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        response.forEach(function(value){
            $('#subcategory').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.subcategory+'</option>');
        });
    }).fail(function(){
            console.log('error: Please reload page and try again!');
    }).always(function(){
            console.log('Complete:');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in the first lines in your controller you are disabling the views, so Volt is never processed. As you are working now, jQuery only receives JSON results, so you are appending JSON rather than Volt. 
You have to choose a path: either use Volt, in which case you have to remove lines 1 in both actions and process the view with parameters, or you keep sending JSON data to jQuery and you set it up properly for processing JSON response (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951810/how-to-parse-json-data-with-jquery-javascript) )

In your case, `getSubcategoryAction()` would look like:

```
public function getSubcategoryAction()
{ 
    //$this->view->disable();  //Replaced by: 
    $this->view->setRenderLevel(
        View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW
     );        
    $id = $this->request->getPost('id');
    $data = Subcat::findBycategory_id($id);   
    foreach($data as $result)
    {
        $resData[] = array('id' => $result->id, 'category_id' => $result->category_id, 'subcategory' => $result->subcategory_name);
    }

    $this->view->setVar('categories', $resData);

}
```

This is assuming that you have set Volt as your render engine in your DI and your Volt template corresponds to ../app/views/index/getSubcategory.phtml, i.e.:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt;

// Register Volt as a service
$di->set(
    'voltService',
    function ($view, $di) {
        $volt = new Volt($view, $di);

        $volt->setOptions(
          [
            'compiledPath'      => '../app/compiled-templates/',
            'compiledExtension' => '.compiled',
          ]
        );

       return $volt;
    }
);

// Register Volt as template engine
$di->set(
    'view',
    function () {
        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

        $view->registerEngines(
          [
            '.volt' => 'voltService',
          ]
        );

        return $view;
    }
);
```

The Volt registration code was copied from: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/volt  Modify the directories according to your App structure.

Comment: Not understand in my case please throw a example related with my code how to use volt to get expected result!

Comment: i follow your instruction and change controller action also jquery! but console.log shows nothing and drop menu not populated

Comment: I just update my full code please check it and tell what im doing wrong to get expected result?

Comment: If you visit `http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getSubcategory` what do you receive? Also, if possible, include the definition of your Volt service.

Comment: Receive undefined in console.log. using: console.log('success:'+value.subcategory_name);

Comment: Ok, and when you visit the url directly with your browser?

Comment: dropdown menu not populate data. just show "choose sub-category" which i set manually in volt.

Comment: a_byte_late i just figure it by changing jquery and controller. i updated my code but the current problem is each time i select option from category subcategory render its data twice. could u plz tel me how to solved?

Comment: I just saw your changes. `getSubcategoryAction()` is again returning a JSON response; if you are going to continue with this path, then you need to disable the view and forget about Volt. Please paste the result when you visit http://localhost/shopping/backend/index/getSubcategory directly in your browser.