# How does one extract a value from a JSON returned by a web service in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951858/475766) looked pretty close but I think there's a fundamental difference between this answer and my problem that makes the answer insufficient for my needs.

From an ajax post, I'm getting a JSON value returned that looks like this:

```
{
   "token": "wegHOIoi32h4gt834ygli",
   "expires": "1496845449"
}
```

I need to save the token value `wegHOIoi32h4gt834ygli` into localStorage.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $(".Results").html(response);
    $.each(response, function (index, element) {
        var token = element.value;
        console.log(token);
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    })
});
```

Now I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '326' in {
>       "token": "wegHOIoi32h4gt834ygli",
>       "expires": 1496845449
>   }

Pretty sure I don't have any idea what's going on at this point. How can I extract the value I'm looking for?

Comment: If `response` is a string, you need to turn it into an object first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the API response is a string, you'll need to parse it into an object with `JSON.parse(responseString)`. This then gives you a plain JavaScript object that you can manipulate and extract values from.

For example, assuming the response is the one from your question:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
    var token = parsedResponse.token;
    console.log(token); // "wegHOIoi32h4gt834ygli"
});
```

Alternatively, if your API is correctly sending it's response with `Content-Type: application/json`, or you tell jQuery to parse it as JSON for you (see `dataType: "json"` in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)), then the problem is coming from the fact that `$.each` tries to iterate over an **array** of value, which you don't have, so you can simply do this:

```
$.ajax(settingsIncudingDataType).done(function (response) {
    var token = response.token;
    console.log(token); // "wegHOIoi32h4gt834ygli"
});
```

Comment: The JSON parsing did it :) I actually had the link for JSON.Parse open on w3schools but figured I could save myself some time by asking before I implemented it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! One thing I find really helpful for quickly experimenting with JS is having Node.js installed on my machine, so I can quickly drop into an interactive Node console - might be worth setting that up if you work on JS often. Also, if this solved it for you, could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: I was trying to mark as accepted but it wouldn't let me lol also I have Node.js since I'm starting Angular but I don't know how to do this thing that you're suggesting with it

Comment: If you have Node.js installed on your machine, you should just be able to type `node` in your terminal to start an interactive session. From there you can type JS code and see the results immediately.